# OLE/COM Object Viewer reports STG_E_FILENOTFOUND

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, com

I have created simple COM DLL using ATL and have added "ATL Simple Object" after that. To be sure server is registering I have placed messagebox:

```
STDAPI DllRegisterServer(void)
{
     MessageBoxA ( NULL, "Hello World!", "Test", MB_OK );
    HRESULT hr = _AtlModule.DllRegisterServer();
        return hr;
}
```

Registering does fine. I decided to look how this object looks with OLE-COM Object Viewer that is part of SDK. Viewer reports error:

```
 "LoadTypelib'(c:\pr\ILight.dll) failed. 
 <No system message defined> STG_E_FILENOTFOUND ($800300002)
```

Does it means my COM dll corrupted? How to make VIewer to show my dll information?

P.S.
Project RC file contians:

**"REGISTRY"**

```
IDR_ILIGHT
    HKCR{}
IDR_LIGHT
    HKCR
    {
AboutiLight.1 = s 'Light Class'
{
    CLSID = s '{DBC53EA8-A51E-4374-B104-06A834273B0C}'
}
AboutiLight = s 'Light Class'
{       
    CurVer = s 'AboutiLight.1'
}
NoRemove CLSID
{
    ForceRemove {DBC53EA8-A51E-4374-B104-06A834273B0C} = s 'Light Class'
    {
        ProgID = s 'AboutiLight.1'
        VersionIndependentProgID = s 'AboutiLight'
        ForceRemove Programmable
        InprocServer32 = s '%MODULE%'
        {
            val ThreadingModel = s 'Apartment'
        }
        TypeLib = s '{1D9F859D-10FF-4827-A341-4A8B8E318A61}'
        Version = s '1.0'
    }
}
    }
```

**String table**

```
String table
ID=IDS_PROJNAME Value=100 Caption ILight
```

**Version**

```
VS_VERSION_INFO
FILEVERSION 1,0,0,1
PRODUCTVERSION 1,0,0,1
FILEMASK 0x3fL
FILEFLAGS 0x0L
FILEOS VOS_NT_WINDOWS32
FILETYPE VFT_DLL
FILESUBTYPE VFT2_UNKNOWN
```

Comment: Registering the server and viewing the type library embedded in the DLL are two entirely different things.  Why the type lib isn't embedded is entirely unclear, check the project's .rc file.  Make sure that your interface actually has methods.

Comment: I'm not sure what should be in .rc file. But it contains 3 folders described at the end of problem description

Comment: Nothing of the quoted from resource script tells that the DLL has the type library. However it might still be fine, since it is most often referenced through `TEXTINCLUDE` section or `.RC` file, which you did not quote.

Answer (score 7):

After having received the same error (STG_E_FILENOTFOUND), and seeing Joe Willcoxson's comment about 64-bit and 32-bit, I was able to find a solution.

If you are using OleView.exe, the OLE/COM Object Viewer, there are actually two versions of it: 32-bit, and 64-bit.  Ensure that you are launching with the proper version of OleView.  The version in the base "BIN" folder of the SDK will be the 32-bit version.  The "x64" folder will have the 64-bit version of the application, which is not fully compatible with older binaries and their typelibs (made in a 32-bit world).

On the other hand, if your new DLL is actively being compiled for x64, then it's highly likely 32-bit OleView will not be able to read the data properly, either.

Answer (score 2):

1) Check to make sure that is the right path to your DLL.

2) Open the DLL itself from Visual Studio and check to be sure that a type library is embedded in the resources.  If a typelib isn't found, add one.

3) If all that fails, did you register it under an administrator account/shell.  If you call regsvr32.exe on it, make sure you are running with elevated privileges.

Comment: 1 Path is right; 2 How to check type library is embedded? Project contains idl file. If I open DLL itself it has folder "TYPELIB" that contains "1" which contains a lot of binary data. 3 Dll is registered under admin rights - checked many times.

Comment: My only other thought is to try and build the DLL for 64-bit (or 32-bit if it's already 64) and see if that works with OleView.  You should also try instantiating with a vb script--making sure to try both 32 and 64 bit versions of wscpript.exe/cscript.exe.

Comment: how to tell visual studio to compile 32 or 64 bit dll?

Comment: Not near my work machine, but basically add a x64 build configurations.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkz9kefa(v=vs.90).aspx